# RCP communication

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I wrote two independent RCP application, let's call them A and B. Is it possible to call and run B from A without setting any dipendences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this..But i assume it would be a normal Java process invoking.
If B is an exe.

```
    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runTime.exec("B");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the executable for B, you can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to execute B from A.